# Cannot import numba in ipython cluster engines?

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, numba, ipython-parallel

I would like to run a calculation on an IPython cluster that uses a custom numba-fied function to run quickly. I try to synchronize the imports using the `sync_imports` method of the `dview` object. The problem is that the engines don't seem to load numba correctly, while numpy get imported just fine... Here's a short "minimal" code that points to the problem:

```py
from IPython.parallel import Client

rc = Client()                      
dview = rc[:]                      

print 'before import'              

with dview.sync_imports():         
   import numpy 
   import numba

print 'no deadlock'
```

When I run this code there is a sort of deadlock happening after the numpy import, and after a while I get this error:

```
before import
importing numpy on engine(s)
importing numba on engine(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ipcltest.py", line 12, in 
    import numba
  File "/c5/shared/Python/2.7.4-shared/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/c5/shared/Python/2.7.4-shared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/parallel/client/view.py", line 496, in sync_imports
    r.get()
  File "/c5/shared/Python/2.7.4-shared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/parallel/client/asyncresult.py", line 119, in get
    self.wait(timeout)
  File "/c5/shared/Python/2.7.4-shared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/parallel/client/asyncresult.py", line 142, in wait
    self._ready = self._client.wait(self.msg_ids, timeout)
  File "/c5/shared/Python/2.7.4-shared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/parallel/client/client.py", line 1063, in wait
    self.spin()
  File "/c5/shared/Python/2.7.4-shared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/parallel/client/client.py", line 1013, in spin
    self._flush_results(self._mux_socket)
  File "/c5/shared/Python/2.7.4-shared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/parallel/client/client.py", line 821, in _flush_results
    raise Exception("Unhandled message type: %s" % msg_type)
Exception: Unhandled message type: apply_request
./ipcltest.py  1.20s user 0.40s system 0% cpu 25:29.11 total
```

Does anyone have any idea about what causes this behaviour ?

Comment: This works without error for me on the latest ipython/notebook, numba and python 2.7